# Searching Chrome with speech input

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am following an Udemy course to create an AI like Jarvis. He takes commands and uses them to completes tasks. I'm having a problem with getting him to search in chrome.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as wb

engine = pyttsx3.init()

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishme():
    speak("Welcome back Summer.")
    speak("Jarvis at your service. How may I help you today?")

def TakeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en.US')
        print(query)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"

    return query

if __name__ == "__main__":

    wishme()

    while True:
        query = TakeCommand().lower()

        if 'search in chrome' in query:
            speak("What should I search?")
            chromepath = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application %s'

            search = TakeCommand().lower()
            wb.get(chromepath).open_new_tab(search+'.com')
```

I'm having trouble with the last if statement and getting Jarvis to take the command and then open a new tab in chrome and search what I asked him to search.

Comment: Please clarify "not working"... Does the elif statement get entered? Does TakeCommand() actually run? I don't think `Application` is a proper executable for `chrome.exe` and the `%s` seems misplaced

Comment: So I'm supposed to be able to say a word that is a site.com and Jarvis is supposed to open that site in a new tab, but he just starts over from the top.

Comment: Please edit your post rather than comment to include your full code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to change the backslashes `(\)` to forward slashes `(/)` and add `chrome.exe` to the end of the path line.